# List of features a Drupal hosting service should have

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, hosting, web-hosting

I'm looking for a hosting service for Drupal to suggest to all my next customers, to be sure I'm not going to have development issues.

I'm writing down a list of features a Drupal hosting service should have:

**1. Control panel with zip compress / decompress functionality**
After I uploaded drupal to new server, I usually don't have ssh access, and php scripts sometimes cause files permissions issues. It is better to do it from control panel.

**2. PHP Memory Limit: 128MB (or more ?)**
I don't want anymore to see out of memory messages. This is an important point.

**3. PHP post_max_size**
Some users couldn't upload long videos (with CCK Upload fields) because of this limit. What's a reasonable value for it ?

**4. Rewrite Module Enabled**
I'm not sure all hosting services have it enabled. Or am I wrong ? I should ask for it if I want to use clean urls, correct ?

**5. IMAP E-mail ?**
I want to be able to setup e-mail services for my customers. They should be able to setup multilple client e-mail applications with their e-mail account and a copy of their e-mails should remain on the server. This is what IMAP protocol does.. correct ? Should I ask for it, if I want this e-mail functionality or I can handle it differently ?

**6. Automatic backup.** I want my website always online. This means that a copy of my drupal installation should be automatically created on a backup server and ready to use if the server is down.

Could you please correct, or suggest features to add ?
Thanks!

Comment: This should be a community wiki; there is no right answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

post_max_size should ideally be slightly larger than upload_max_size.

IMO, there are few more things to consider. For instance:

- PHP not running in Safe Mode (this introduces enormous issues).
- PHP is preferably running as an Apache module (CGI/FCGI are fine if you know what you're doing).
- Drupal user has ALL PRIVILEGES on its database (to create temporary tables for instance).
- A large key and index buffer size for MySQL (useful for large queries carried by Views).
- Allow Apache user to access drupal.org (yes, I had a situation where a hosting provider didn't allow it and Drupal status updates were useless).

Comment: See http://www.joomlaperformance.com/articles/webcasts/why_mod_php_is_bad_for_performance_52_58.html

Comment: This doesn't prove your point.
http://2bits.com/articles/apache-fcgid-acceptable-performance-and-better-resource-utilization.html
http://buytaert.net/album/drupal/drupal-4.7-fastcgi-vs-mod_php

Comment: You are right, I am confusing two different things. Your 2nd article sums it up pretty well: "If pure speed is what you are after, then stay with mod_php. However, for better resource usage and efficiency, consider moving to fcgid." That's what I meant.

Answer (score 1):

You missed one!

**PHP > 5.2**

redhat/centos isn't a new enough version

Comment: Your memory limit should be fine. Not too sure about the post post limit but you'll probably need the pecl upload progress bar (I think that's what it's called). It's essential for large files.

Answer (score 1):

There are some more obscure MySQL configurations that can be problematic for Drupal, as far as I remember you need CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE permissions for the Drupal search.

Depending on your site a lower PHP memory limit should also be OK.

Don't rely on the Hosting Provider's backup, always make your own backups. A ready to use  backup server won't be part of any affordable webspace.

Most hosters allow you to try out their services on a temporary account, I would just do that to see if there are any problems.

Comment: So.. should I ask my hosting provider if I can create temporary tables ? Something else ?

Comment: Just try it out on a test account, that way you can also find other problems that weren't mentioned here.

Comment: I'm actually trying to have a complete list of requirements. What other problems could I have ?